# Android Layout Help - Half of screen should be upside down

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm OK with the java for this beginning app I'm attempting.  But the XML still boggles my mind a little.  I've included a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

And here is the code I have so far.  I'm happy with the way it came out, I just need to know how to reverse that first half:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/opponent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/opPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/opMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/plPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/plMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add:

```
android:rotation="180"
```

to the View or ViewGroup that you wish to rotate. In this case, the `LinearLayout` with the id of `@+id/opponent`

EDIT: Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/opponent"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF8833"
    >
    <View
      android:id="@+id/emptyview"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      />
    <Button
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/emptyview"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="#999999"
      android:text="Button 1"
      />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emptyview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/opponent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#33FF33"
      >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/emptyview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/emptyview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#999999"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emptyview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but when I put it in and reload the graphic interface, it doesn't show any change.  the 2 buttons are still sitting on the center of the screen

Comment: I see that.  weird.  I'm getting: error. no resource found for attribute "rotation" in package "android"

Comment: UGH!  that's so annoying.  I was building for 2.3 in stead of 4.0.

Comment: New Question.  the layout LOOKS correct.  But the opponent buttons are actually still on the center of the screen.  Just the views are on top

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I've compiled and ran it just as posted and it works just as expected for me.

Comment: You're awesome. Don't know why it was acting weird in the emulator, but when I loaded it onto my phone, it worked.  Thanks again